# Apply href on image, class or id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm a designer. I need to put the same href contained in `class="kt-testimonial-title"` in `id="slick-slide10"`, or in `class="kt-testimonial-item-wrap kt-testimonial-item-0"`, or in `class="kt-testimonial-image"`.

Is it possible with jquery or javascript?

Section:

```html
<div class="kt-blocks-testimonial-carousel-item kb-slide-item slick-slide slick-current slick-active" style="width: 337px;" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control10" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="kt-testimonial-item-wrap kt-testimonial-item-0" style="border-color:rgba(238, 238, 238, 1);padding-top:40px;padding-right:40px;padding-bottom:40px;padding-left:40px;max-width:500px">
<div class="kt-testimonial-text-wrap">
  <div class="kt-testimonial-media-wrap">
    <div class="kt-testimonial-media-inner-wrap" style="border-radius:px;border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px">
      <div class="kadence-testimonial-image-intrisic" style="padding-bottom:100%">
        <div class="kt-testimonial-image" style="background-image:url(&quot;http://homeagent.devup.site/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/pegn.png&quot;);background-size:Contain"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="kt-testimonial-title-wrap">
    <h6 class="kt-testimonial-title">
      <a href="https://revistapegn.globo.com/Tecnologia/noticia/2020/04/coronavirus-de-ti-gestao-de-ponto-o-mercado-das-empresas-que-ajudam-no-home-office.html" target="_blank" aria-label=" (opens in a new tab)" rel="noreferrer noopener"
        class="ek-link" tabindex="0">De TI a gestão de ponto: o<br> mercado das empresas que<br> ajudam no home office</a>
    </h6>
  </div>
  <div class="kt-testimonial-content-wrap">
    <div class="kt-testimonial-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Source:

http://homeagent.devup.site/sobre/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! James, you James, in summary, you need put a link to your image?

Comment: Yes, it is a slider, seeing at the source, note that the titles have links, and the images do not

Comment: We need more detail about what you try doing. "is it possible?" Yes. Why Javacript? Why not only wrapper your all `kb-slide-item` with a anchor instead of?

Comment: There are 16 images / texts / links. I believe that with the example of a link I can replicate for others. I appreciate your attention.

Comment: Why Javacript? Or Jquery? Because they are parts of the html code that are not static.

Comment: You are welcome! Other tip about question: Always try format your code for clarify - https://webformatter.com/html

Comment: It remains for me to control these sections with CSS (which does not insert hrefs), and other resources.

Comment: True, in other tasks I organized the code better. Good indication of tool this webformater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
// add common alias jquery 
$ = jQuery;

const anchors = $('.kt-blocks-testimonial-carousel-item a.ek-link');

$.each(anchors, function (i, e) {
  let anchor = $(e);
  let text = anchor.text();
  let textContainer = anchor.parent();
  let newAnchor = anchor.clone().empty();
  let carouselItem = anchor.parents('.kt-blocks-testimonial-carousel-item');

  carouselItem.wrap(newAnchor);
  textContainer.text(text);
});
```

That is a not beautiful code but works on javascript console at http://homeagent.devup.site/sobre/

Comment: Working! I believed that I would have to add the links one at a time. You went further. All title links are replicated for all images. Excellent job!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```html
<div class="kt-blocks-testimonial-carousel-item kb-slide-item slick-slide slick-current slick-active" style="width: 337px;" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide10" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control10" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false"><div class="kt-testimonial-item-wrap kt-testimonial-item-0" style="border-color:rgba(238, 238, 238, 1);padding-top:40px;padding-right:40px;padding-bottom:40px;padding-left:40px;max-width:500px"><div class="kt-testimonial-text-wrap"><div class="kt-testimonial-media-wrap"><div class="kt-testimonial-media-inner-wrap" style="border-radius:px;border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px"><div class="kadence-testimonial-image-intrisic" style="padding-bottom:100%"><div class="kt-testimonial-image" style="background-image:url(&quot;http://homeagent.devup.site/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/pegn.png&quot;);background-size:Contain"></div></div></div></div><div class="kt-testimonial-title-wrap"><h6 class="kt-testimonial-title"><a href="https://revistapegn.globo.com/Tecnologia/noticia/2020/04/coronavirus-de-ti-gestao-de-ponto-o-mercado-das-empresas-que-ajudam-no-home-office.html" target="_blank" aria-label=" (opens in a new tab)" rel="noreferrer noopener" class="ek-link" tabindex="0">De TI a gestão de ponto: o<br> mercado das empresas que<br> ajudam no home office</a></h6></div><div class="kt-testimonial-content-wrap"><div class="kt-testimonial-content"></div></div></div></div></div>
    
<script>
        var slidesArr = document.querySelectorAll('.slick-slide');
        slidesArr.forEach(function(slide){
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = slide.querySelector('.kt-testimonial-title a').getAttribute('href');
            a.appendChild(slide.querySelector('.kt-testimonial-item-wrap'));
            slide.appendChild(a);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: No. Does it make a difference to insert those script in header, body or footer? Thanks.

Comment: Updated the script.
Place it at the bottom just before body closes. It should work.

</body>

Comment: I appreciate your attempts. Also I ran other scripts from stackoverflow but to no avail